# Подскажите по коду

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String text = reader.readLine(); //вводим строку (слова с символами) 
String replacedString = text.replaceAll("\\p{P}"," ").toLowerCase(); // тут заменяем всю пунктуацию на пробелы
replacedString=replacedString.replaceAll("\\s"," "); // заменяем все пробелы на пробелы если это так то получается нет смысла в этой строчке?

String splitString[] = replacedString.split(" "); // добавляем в массив строк слова используя пробел как разделение
```

Видел такой код посмотрите пожалуйста правильно ли я все понял по комментариям. Цель кода разделить строку слов разделенных знаками препинания на массив слов чтобы потом из него найти одинаковые слова.

Comment: коментарии корректные. Объективно автозамены не нужны, метод `split(String regex)` класса `String` получает на вход регулярное выражение, а не обязательный пробел. Можно было просто задать знаки препинания в аргументы метода и все.

Comment: \s - это whitespaces, в том числе табуляции

Comment: Цель кода разделить строку в массив слов, используя пробел в качестве разделителя.

Answer (score 0):

Не описано в комментарии: toLowerCase() возвращает строку, преобразованную в нижний регистр. (Строка 3)

\s Соответствует пробелам. Эквивалентно [\t\n\r\f]. Так называемые пробельные символы, а не только пробелы.

Массив получите.